# Error Using Realloc() and pointers

Tags: c, file-io, runtime-error, realloc

I have been writing a program but have been having some problems when it runs. 
The file to be read contains 11 columns, but an unspecified amount of rows to be read.

I have been using realloc() to have dynamic memory creation to change the input files read. However upon running the program i receive the following trace. I have no idea what it means, nor how to fix it. The program compiles fine, but aborts to a memory dump and this screen. I can upload the entire code if desired, however it is quite long.

[image]

```
 do //Safe to assume atleast one line of information will be present
{
    j++;
    if(j>5) //Will resize the array if there are more than 5 rows
    {
        Poke = realloc(Poke, j * 100); //* 100 needed to account for strings
        Type = realloc(Type, j * 100);
        Height = realloc(Height,j);
        Weight = realloc(Weight,j);
        HP = realloc(HP, j);
        Attack = realloc(Attack, j);
        Defense = realloc(Defense, j);
        SPA = realloc(SPA, j);
        SPD = realloc(SPD, j);
        Speed = realloc(Speed, j);
        Evo = realloc(Evo, j * 100);
    }

    //Read and store all values
    fscanf(ifp, "%s %s %f %f %i %i %i %i %i %i %s", (Poke + 100*j),
    (Type + 100*j),(Height + j),(Weight + j),(HP + j),(Attack + j),
    (Defense + j),(SPA + j),(SPD + j),(Speed + j),(Evo + 100*j));
} while(!feof(ifp));
```

where Poke, Type, and Evo are all character points
Height and Weight are float
rest at ints

input data from file is of this form

```
Charmander  Fire        0.6     8.5     39  52      43      60      50      65      Charmeleon
Bulbasaur   Grass       0.7     6.9     45  49      49      65      65      45      Ivysaur
```

Comment: I don't think anybody can help you unless you post a part of the problematic code.

Comment: Offhand guess, you are writing outside allocated addresses.  As chrk says, need to see code to say more.

Comment: You may get a more useful crash dump from `valgrind`.

Comment: Debugging such problem includes: 1) remove lines until the problem goes away; 2) run a tool like `valgrind`; 3) put lots of print statements in your code and see what values are - and what the last thing is that got printed.

Comment: Question has been update with portions of problematic code

Comment: A wild SEGFAULT appears...

Comment: You've no idea what's going on since you don't capture the return value from `fscanf()`, which will let you know how successful it is, or isn't.  Always, but always, test the result of your input functions. Note the `feof()` won't be true until `fscanf()` failed to read one lot of data, which usually leads to trouble.  You need to study how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: Anyway - your `%s` modifiers within `fscanf` may be overflowing their buffer; or `Poke` etc. may not have been correctly set up in the code before the code snippet you showed. Can you post a complete program that gives the problem? (cut out any irrelevant stuff and check that it still gives the error when you run it).

Comment: @Jonathan, I think the `feof` won't be a problem in this case; unless he switches to `fgets`/`sscanf` he has to do the `reallocs` before trying to read a line, and then it doesn't matter whether the failure is detected by `feof` or by the wrong count returned from `fscanf`. (However he should either check `ferror` also, or preferably do as you suggest and use the `fscanf` return value as the test condition)

Comment: You should probably be using an array of structures rather than 11 parallel arrays.  It would make things easier to understand — for you and anyone else trying to understand your code.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Suppose `j` is `0` and the file is tragically empty. The code increments `j` to `1`, (there's enough space because 5 units of space were preallocated — I presume), the `fscanf()` fails with EOF, and the `feof()` fires so the loop breaks.  Unless `j` is decremented after the loop (it could be; the code isn't shown), the system thinks there's 1 entry when in fact there were none, so everything has gone to hell.

Comment: `j` would also be incremented if the loop breaks due to `fscanf` not returning `11`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I'm not a fan of `do { … } while (…);` loops, and this sort of mess is why. If the data was in a structure, you'd allocate a new structure, (attempt to) read data into it, and add the structure to the main array if the read is successful and jettison the structure if it is not.  The exact details depend on whether the strings in the structure are fixed size arrays or are themselves pointers.  With fixed size arrays, you'd simply read into a local structure, then copy that into a dynamically allocated structure in the array of structures.

Comment: Yes that'd be infinitely better

Comment: E.g `Height = realloc(Height,j*sizeof(float));` destroy alloced memory  by `fscanf(...%f...(Height + j)...);`

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be saying that you passed zero as the size for realloc (`realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00000000`).  Could your code be mistakenly trying to set the new size to something invalid?  Try printing out the size before calling realloc and ensure it's what you expect.

If that's not it then showing at least the portion of your code that calls realloc would help.